# Firebase - Let one user send an invitation to another user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to make an Ionic/firebase App

Needed functionality:

- The user can signup/login.
- The user can create a **Team**
- User A can enter a name/email of user B and send an invite so user B can join user A's team

What i already have:

- Users can Sign Up/login
- Users can create a team

What i need:

- letting one user send an invitation to another user without exposing to much user/team data to all other the users

My database:

```
{
  "teams": {
       "-KSDNasns-idTeamAfrompush": {
              "teamName": "Team A",
              "teamMembers": {
                    "userA-uuid": {
                          "userName": "UserA",
                          "userEmail": "userA@test.test"
                    }
               }
        }
    },
    "users":{
        "userA-uuid": {
            "name":"User A",
            "email": "userA@test.test"
            "teams": {
                 "-KasjAJ-somepushid": {
                          "title":"Team A",
                          "id": "-KSDNasns-idTeamAfrompush"
                 }
             },
         },
         "userB-uuid": {
            "name":"User B",
            "email": "userB@test.test"
            "teams": {} //basically not even there
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My first thought was:

- Giving read rights for the users list to every user so they can
  search for a user by email/name
- giving read/write rights for a team to a user as long as users.hasChild(auth.uuid) (so as long as he is a member of the team)
- giving the right to create a new team entry in any users team list, so that when you add a user to your team, you just write your team in his teamlist and add him to your teams user list

but that doesnt seem very secure

thanks in advance for any answers

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?